# How to add label above the graph using dc.js?

Tags: dc.js

When I select any particular field in the bar graph, all the graphs changes accordingly.

I want to introduce a heading above the graphs which should show which data is currently displayed in the graphs and the count.

So what changes should I make in my code?

```js
var data = [{
    "city": "New York",
        "neighborhood": "N/A",
        "hits": 200
}, {
    "city": "New York",
        "neighborhood": "Brooklyn",
        "hits": 225
}, {
    "city": "New York",
        "neighborhood": "Queens",
        "hits": 1
}, {
    "city": "San Francisco",
        "neighborhood": "Chinatown",
        "hits": 268
}, {
    "city": "San Francisco",
        "neighborhood": "Downtown",
        "hits": 22
}, {
    "city": "Seattle",
        "neighborhood": "N/A",
        "hits": 2
}, {
    "city": "Seattle",
        "neighborhood": "Freemont",
        "hits": 25
}];
var pieChart = dc.pieChart("#pieChart"),
    rowChart = dc.rowChart("#rowChart");
var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    cityDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.city;
    }),
    cityGroup = cityDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.hits;
    }),
    neighborhoodDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.neighborhood;
    }),
    neighborhoodGroup = neighborhoodDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return d.hits;
    });

pieChart.width(200)
    .height(200)
    .slicesCap(4)
    .dimension(cityDimension)
    .group(cityGroup);
pieChart.filter = function() {};

rowChart.width(500)
    .height(500)
    .dimension(neighborhoodDimension)
    .group(neighborhoodGroup);

dc.renderAll();
```

```html
<div id="pieChart"> </div>
<div id="rowChart"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying the current filters, you can use `span`s with `class='reset' and`class='filter'` within the charts, as demonstrated in the [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html)

For displaying the counts of records filtered, you can use the [dataCount widget](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.dataCount) or the [numberDisplay](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.numberDisplay) widget.

Anything else, you'll have to implement the display itself, probably hooking the [filtered event](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinonevent-listener--basemixin) to determine when the filters have changed, and changing your own div using e.g. d3 or jQuery.

Comment: but what i wanna do for my website is that i have a long list of customers and for each customer selection the graphs change according to the customer data , so i want to introduce a label above the graphs that currently the data displayed is for this customer and for this particular service. So , what should i do to do that.

Comment: So you are filtering on the customer in crossfilter? Is that filter via dc.js or external to it? If it's via dc.js the `filtered` event is the way to go.